# Open a new Form below from a Textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to open a form exactly below from a `Textbox`. My problem is that I include some invisible panels. When a panel become `Visible` and the `Textbox` is changing it's `Location`, then i am getting wrong new WinForm start position.

Here is what i am trying to do.

```
 foreach (Control ctrl in myPanel.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl is TextBox)
            {
                tb = (TextBox)ctrl;

                tb.DoubleClick += Tb_DoubleClick;
            }
          
        }

 private void Tb_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox ts = sender as TextBox;
        if (ts.BackColor == Color.White)
        {
            int x = ts.Location.X;
            int y = ts.Location.Y;
            VirtualNumPad2 frm = new VirtualNumPad2();
            frm.Location = new Point(x, y+200 );               
            frm.ShowDialog();

           
        }
      

    }
```

[image]

Comment: `foreach (var tb in myPanel.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()) tb.DoubleClick += Tb_DoubleClick;` (slightly simpler way to write that loop)

Comment: What start position do you want if the panel is not visible?

Comment: I have upload a picture for understading better what i am trying to do.

Comment: When the panel becomes in/visible, handle that event and recalculate the location.

Comment: I agree with @CodingYoshi. You need to recalculate location based on visibility. I did something similar in past.
         if (GlobalParameters.IsSupportPanel1)
            {
                lciPanel1.Visibility = LayoutVisibility.Always;
                esiLeft.Width = (lycgMain.Width - lycgMain.Padding.Left - lycgMain.Padding.Right - 96 * 8) / 2;
            }
            else
            {
                lciPanel1.Visibility =LayoutVisibility.Never;
                esiLeft.Width = (lycgMain.Width - lycgMain.Padding.Left - lycgMain.Padding.Right - 96 * 7) / 2;
            }

Comment: I forgot to mention(i don't know if it is matter) that the main window is child into another winform. I dont know if this has to do with this. I just can't understand why i cant take the real textbox position. Example if form will be resized, it changes my form position.

Comment: @user10775950 Doesn't matter the main window child to another. Just you can resize on the current  visibility.